# How to change the text "optional arguments" in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

For some reason I do not use positional arguments in my program but accept "optional" arguments only, controlling whether an argument is truly optional by facilities like `narg='?'` or `action='store_true'`. Thus the "optional arguments" in the help text will be misleading. Can I display it simply as "arguments"? Thank you.

Comment: Wait, I thought you can't make an optional argument mandatory…

Comment: Ah, you mean, you are checking for their presence manually. That's insane… You are adding your own checks, now trying to override some builtin behaviour, when switching to positional arguments is so easy.

Comment: @kirelagin I want to make my arguments not "position-sensitive" so I use "optional arguments" for all arguments

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, looking at the `argparse` source it seems to me that it's as simple as overwriting the `title` of `parser._optionals`, like this:

```
parser._optionals.title = "my mandatory arguments, they are actually optionals, but I'll check for their presence"
```

Probably I should mention that it's a dirty hack, and your whole idea is a bit insane, since switching to positional arguments is so easy to do, and optional arguments are *optional*.

Comment: I think both answers are equally well. So if you don't mind can I accept the answer from @falsetru because he/she has lower reputation?

Comment: @ziyuang Well, sure, I don't mind. But I still suggest using my answer, as it directly does what you need, without iterating over all the groups and title comparisons.

Comment: I should be more clear: I suggest not doing it at all. But you clearly don't need to iterate over all groups.

Comment: A perfectly valid use case with required "optionals" is when requiring the presence of a mutually exclusive group.

Comment: Non-positional arguments aren't always optional. I know the documentation doesn't recommend using required=True for add_argument, but it's still possible to do, and in some cases it makes more sense. For one it makes the command line itself more self documenting than positional arguments. I consider it an oxymoron that they allow the required=True parameter for add_argument while keeping the title "optional arguments:" in the autogenerated help text.

Comment: How can I also make changes for the `positional arguments`?

Comment: @alper - parser._positionals.title = "subcommands"

Answer (score 4):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for grp in parser._action_groups:
    if grp.title == 'optional arguments':
        grp.title = 'arguments'
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and exposing the `_action_groups` to me! But I somehow think @kirelagin's answer is more direct, so I will accept his.